# Problem posting on Super User

Tags: discussion, answers, amazon

I tried to answer a couple of headphone related questions on Super User. Once I pasted in an Amazon url, and the answer did not appear; None of my answers made since actually appear as answers on the question. What did I do wrong?

Here's some of the Questions. If you see a reply by me, then it's something messed up on my side:

[https://superuser.com/questions/1805/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1805/answe)
[Macbook Pro - Sound doesn't work and there's a red light coming out of my headphone jack](https://superuser.com/questions/37777/answer)

I had another open but I closed it. My user page doesn't show recent posts. But I did manage to shorten one answer to a comment:

https://superuser.com/users/2650?tab=recent#sort-top

I did manage to edit this post: https://superuser.com/questions/12472/recomendations-for-headphones-to-use-when-coding/12529#12529

**Update**
Coming back to this 10 hours later, things work normally. Whatever it was that prevented me from posting is gone. I was using Safari 4.0.3 on OS X 10.6 for the curious.

Comment: Can you post some links to the questions.

Comment: Have you tried it with different browsers?

Comment: You're on what OS using what browser?

Answer (score 2):

Testing an [Amazon URL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142000280).

Works. Looks like your problem has nothing to do with Amazon :-)

Test without [superfluous stuff](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142000280). [Even shorter.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0142000280)

Comment: Actually I deleted the SEO part so it became: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0142000280/ref=cm%5Fcr%5Fpr%5Fproduct%5Ftop&tag=stackoverlow-20

Answer (score 1):

Once you click "post your answer", do you see the list of answers? If not, make sure you do, otherwise, you may be asked to enter a CAPTCHA. If you can see the list of answers, but your answer is **not** there, you need to email the team at the link at the bottom of every SU page.

Comment: I do see all the other answers, but not mine. I never hit a captcha, which normally I get every other answer or so.